# Image gallery with relevant text in another div in query

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/afde38dc9c.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/afde38dc9c.jpg)

i need a image gallery like this. image count is dynamic. when i navigate left, img-3 will be center image and img-3 content should be loaded in img-2content div. i need a script to do this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/